# Payroll System using custom LinkedList Class

Tags: java, class, generics, linked-list

I am in process of writing a Payroll application using linked list. The aim is to read multiple files and store their content in a linked list. Then the program will use another class to output the desired data from linked to another text file. Later the files will be replaced with database tables.

My TestReadFile Class reads data and stores in linked list, then supposed to read it. 
The LinkedListClass and LinkedListNode Class should be generic.

I would like to store object with each department in separate objects that then will be place in linkedlist and when need I can retrieve the objects from linked list.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks a lot

```
package payroll;
public class Department implements iDepartment
{
    private int deptID;
    private String deptName, deptLoc;

    public Department()
    {
        deptID = 0;
        deptName = "";
        deptLoc = "";
    }

    public Department(int deptID, String deptName, String deptLoc)
    {
        setDeptID(deptID);
        setDepName(deptName);
        setDeptLoc(deptLoc);
    }

    public void setDeptID(int deptID)
    {
        this.deptID = deptID;
    }

    public void setDepName(String deptName)
    {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptLoc(String deptLoc)
    {
        this.deptLoc = deptLoc;
    }

    public int getDeptID()
    {
        return deptID;
    }

    public String getDeptName()
    {
        return deptName;
    }

    public String getDeptLoc()
    {
        return deptLoc;
    }
}

package payroll;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestReadFile 
{
    private static Scanner inFile;    
    private static Department department;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Department.in"));

        LinkedListClass dept = new LinkedListClass();        

        inFile.useDelimiter(";");
//        while(inFile.hasNextLine())
//        {            
            department = new Department();
            department.setDeptID(inFile.nextInt());
            department.setDepName(inFile.next());
            department.setDeptLoc(inFile.next());            
            dept.addLast(department);                        
//        }
//

//      dept.outputObject();    
        System.out.println("Department ID: " + dept.outputObject().toString());             
    }
}

public class LinkedListClass<T> implements iLinkedListClass<T>
{
    private LinkedListNode<T> head, tail, trav, p;
    private int count;


    public LinkedListClass()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public void addFirst(T data)
    {
        p = new LinkedListNode<T>(data, null);
        p.setLink(head);
        head = p;
    }

    public void addLast(T data)
    {
        p = new LinkedListNode<T>(data, null);

        if(head == null)
        {
            head = p;
            tail = p;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.setLink(p);
            tail = p;
        }
    }

    public void removePosition(int pos)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> prev;
        count = 0;

        if(pos == 0)
        {
            head = head.getLink();
        }

        else if(pos < size())
        {
            prev = head;
            for (int i = 1; i <= (pos - 1); i++)
            {
                prev = prev.getLink();
            }
            prev.setLink(prev.getLink().getLink());

            //if last one to be deleted
            if (prev.getLink() == null)
            {
                tail = prev;
            }
        }
    }

    public void print()
    {
        trav = head;

        while(trav != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Value: " + trav.getInfo());
            trav = trav.getLink();
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        trav = head;
        count = 0;

        while(trav != null)
        {
            count++;
            trav = trav.getLink();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean search(T data)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        trav = head;

        while(trav != null)
        {
            if(trav.getLink() != null)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            trav = trav.getLink();
        }
        if(found)
        {
            System.out.println("Value searched is: " + data);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Value does not exist in the list");
        }
        return found;
    }

    public void insert(T data, int pos)
    {
        trav = head;

        if((pos <= size()) && (pos > 0))
        {
            count = 1;
            while(count <= pos)
            {
                if(count == pos)
                {
                    p = new LinkedListNode(data , null);
                    p.setLink(trav.getLink());
                    trav.setLink(p);
                }
                trav = trav.getLink();
                count++;
            }
        }
        else if(pos <= 0)
        {
            addFirst(data);
        }
        else if(pos > size())
        {
            addLast(data);
        }        
    }

    public int position(T data)
    {
        int pos = -1;
        trav = head;
        while(trav != null)
        {
            if(trav.getInfo() != null)
            {
                return pos;
            }
            pos++;
            trav = trav.getLink();
        }
        return -1;
    }    

    public T outputObject()
    {
        trav = head;
        return trav.getInfo();
    }
}


package payroll;
public class LinkedListNode<T>
{
    private T data;
    private LinkedListNode<T> link;

    public LinkedListNode(T info, LinkedListNode<T> link)
    {
        this.data = info;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setInfo(T info)
    {
        this.data = info;
    }

    public void setLink(LinkedListNode<T> link)
    {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public T getInfo()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public LinkedListNode<T> getLink()
    {
        return this.link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should break down your problem by the Classes (objects) you will create, not the procedural work you want to do. Example: in your case  you appear to have a Company that will be composed of one or more Departments.  So .. create a Company class, and give it a method to read departments in, etc.

For example, consider the code below.

**Main Class**

```
package com.example.accounting;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Main {
// Object fields
private static Main me;
private Company company;
private LinkedList<Department> departments;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    me = new Main();
    me.doWork(args);

}

private void doWork(String[] args) {
    //TODO accept file name as an argument?!

    company = new Company();
    company.addDepartment("Department.in");
    company.listDepartments();

    departments = company.getDepartments();
}
}
```

**Company Class**

```
package com.example.accounting;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Company {
// Object fields
LinkedList<Department> departments = null;

public Company() {
    departments = new LinkedList<Department>();
}

public boolean addDepartment(String file) {
    Scanner source = null;

    try {
        source = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error trying to read " + file + ": " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    source.useDelimiter(";");

    while(source.hasNextLine()) {
        int departmentId = source.nextInt();
        String departmentName = source.next();
        String departmentLocation = source.next();
        departments.add(new Department(departmentId, departmentName, departmentLocation));
    }
    source.close();
    return true;
}

public LinkedList<Department> getDepartments() {
    return departments;
}

public void listDepartments() {

    for (Department dept : departments) {
        System.out.println(" " + dept.getDeptId() + ". " + dept.getDeptName() + ", " + dept.getDeptLoc());
    }
}
}
```

**Department Class**

```
package com.example.accounting;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Company {
    // Object fields
    LinkedList departments = null;

```
public Company() {
    departments = new LinkedList<Department>();
}

public boolean addDepartment(String file) {
    Scanner source = null;

    try {
        source = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error trying to read " + file + ": " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    source.useDelimiter(";");

    while(source.hasNextLine()) {
        int departmentId = source.nextInt();
        String departmentName = source.next();
        String departmentLocation = source.next();
        departments.add(new Department(departmentId, departmentName, departmentLocation));
    }
    source.close();
    return true;
}

public LinkedList<Department> getDepartments() {
    return departments;
}

public void listDepartments() {

    for (Department dept : departments) {
        System.out.println(" " + dept.getDeptId() + ". " + dept.getDeptName() + ", " + dept.getDeptLoc());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you ErstwhileIII for your answer. I will make some changes and repost it later.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to my problem. I had to specify what objects will be placed in linkedlist. Now after placing class that will be used in linked list I am able to access the methods that are part of department. Before I was just getting reference to the object.  LinkedListClass<Department> dept = new LinkedListClass<Department>(); dept.outputObject().getDeptID();